# Chrome Developer Tools Response/Preview Tab "Pretty Print" or "Formatting"

Tags: xml, json, google-chrome

Does anyone know of a tool or extension to the chrome developer tools that will take the response of a request and format it if it's XML or JSON.  I've done quite a bit of looking and have not been able to find any type of tool to properly format the response tab given xml or json response text.

[image]

Comment: I think you can paste it into [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and it'll format it for you.

Comment: Looking for something wear I don't have to copy and paste the content out of chrome.  I'm already using several tools depending on what I'm doing to format the response so it is more readable, but I'm looking to save time.  If I don't have to cut and paste every time I look at the response, it would be more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be not exact one. But I watch requests and open what I need with [jsonview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) about json.

Answer (score 83):

In your screenshot, you just select the 'preview' tab.  Works for me, anyway.  Maybe you don't have the Content-Type response header set correctly?

It works if the response code is 200.  (Maybe if its 2xx).  I found it doesn't work if the response code is 500, though.

Comment: What does the header exactly needs to be? I use `Content-type: text/xml` and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` and under Preview, it's still in plain text and on one line. I tried `Content-type: application/xml` and that didn't pretty print the XML either.

Comment: @romacafe (and to others who can see the XML formatted in the Preview tab), what is the content-type returned by your server? More than 2 years after this question was first asked, I am still not seeing the XML formatted in the Preview tab, now on Chrome 39.

Comment: Its been awhile...  Pretty sure it was `application/xml`, and as I noted, XML wasn't formatted for me if the response code was in the 500 range, regardless of content type.

Comment: I don't like this. The preview is not pretty print, but parsed and displayed in structured format. You have to open each json property separtely, in case of complex replies. For JSON Api replies, this is not practical at all.

Comment: @blueFast in Chrome developer console wherever there is hierarchical data, such as in the Preview, Elements, and Console views, you can right click on any collapsible line and choose "Expand Recursively" and "Collapse Children" to expand and collapse all inner elements at once.

Answer (score 4):

An other way to handle this, is to right click the request in the network tab of the developers tools and select "Copy Response".  Then in the console window enter the following:

```
var a =
```

Then paste and hit enter.

Next enter the following:

```
a
```

Then hit enter again, the entire JSON response will be displayed in an expandable/collapsible form.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome now has a button for pretty printing responses:

[image: Pretty print button]

Answer (score 1):

I wish Chrome would try to parse responses even when there is no Content-type header. But, luckily [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will. You have to use Firefox, but it's worth it when you're dealing with XML.

Answer (score 0):

Try format it in the source.
In case of PHP and DomDocument:

```
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
```

Seems Chrome doesn't offer easy solution.

Answer (score -1):

I promise this is good enough...

- Install [JSON Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh?hl=en-US).
- Look for the request on Network > Fetch/XHR
- Double-click the request you're interested in the side panel called **Name** on the left

*It will open a new tab but it's super fast and the formatting is pristine...*

Comment: This doesn't work, it just opens a new tab with the URL that the request went to.

Comment: that's exacty what it does, i said it in the answer, i use this everyday, you should see the JSON payload formatted if you installed JSON Viewer, you can even inspect this stackoverflow page and double click any of the xhr requests, for example the `en.json`